# What is a modern way to implement a test-suite-builder for a test-class with boost?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, c++17, boost-test

The examples in the documentation of *Boost.Test* seem to be mostly refering to C++03 code.

I wonder if there is a more C++14/C++17-way of putting together the `BOOST_TEST_CASE`s in `init_unit_test_suite`?

This is what I derived from the documentation. I only exchanged `boost::bind` with lambdas. I can not think of any further "modernization" of that code. Can anyone?

Intro:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <memory> // shared ptr

using namespace boost::unit_test;
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
```

Test class:

```
class test_class {
public:
    void test_method1() {
        BOOST_CHECK( true /* test assertion */ );
    }
    void test_method2() {
        BOOST_CHECK( false /* test assertion */ );
    }
};
```

Building the suite:

```
test_suite*
init_unit_test_suite( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    auto tester = std::make_shared<test_class>();
    auto &ts = framework::master_test_suite();
    ts.add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( [=](){ tester->test_method1(); } ));
    ts.add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( [=](){ tester->test_method2(); } ));
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I'd figure out a way to get rid of the `.add` calls and use `{}`s to bulk-add at least.  But this may be more on topic at code review; go over there and check if it meets their standards.

Comment: pinging @GennadiyRozental for adding initializer_list support :)

Comment: and also @Raffi as the other Boost.Test maintainer

Comment: The question that comes to my mind would be "why do you want to use a test class"? If you want to share a state between several test cases, best would be to use a fixture. Otherwise there is little a test class adds.